Why must there be a colon after the `compact /s'?
I would like to decompress everything on the C:\ drive.  I expect the command I must use is:
compact /u /i /s C:\

or, if I'm already in C:\ then
compact /u /i /s .

However, MS Learn advises that the actual command is:
compact /u /i /s:\

I thought this was a typo, and tried the former two commands, and each of them decompressed only the root directory of C:\
I tried the latter command, and sure enough, this was what I needed.  However, when a colon needs to be present is not documented anywhere, whether in MS Learn or after compact /?.
When is a colon necessary after the /s?  Why did the former commands not work?

The command on the website is the same command that you say works, so I am confused, by what you say does not work. There is a huge difference between :/ and C:/ in the Windows directory perspective default is the current directory. :/ is the entire disk C:/ is just the root directory

@Ramhound But I am doing the current directory with a /s switch-- so it should do all subdirectories, making it the entire disk-- no?  Also, how do you know :/ is the entire disk? Is that documented somewhere?  (I edited my post to clarify your underlined question to me).

I'm voting to close this one. Unless the person who answers worked with Microsoft, it is going to be a guess as to why it works this way.

@LPChip I was hoping to find some documentation regarding when else this might be applicable.


/S:\ performs the chosen operation on files in the root directory (of the current volume) and all subdirectories.
You use compact /u /i /s:\; please note the /u switch description (and pay your attention to the /EXE switch):

/u Uncompresses the specified directory or file. Directories are marked so any files added afterwards aren't compressed. If the /EXE parameter is specified, only files compressed as executables are uncompressed; if you don't specify the /EXE parameter, only NTFS compressed files are uncompressed.



The /S switch is documented in compact /?

COMPACT [/C | /U] [/S[:dir]] [/A] [/I] [/F] [/Q] [/EXE[:algorithm]]
        [/CompactOs[:option] [/WinDir:dir]] [filename [...]]


as well as in the newest online doc:

compact [/C | /U] [/S[:dir]] [/A] [/I] [/F] [/Q] [/EXE[:algorithm]] [/CompactOs[:option] [/windir:dir]] [filename [...]]


However, [/S[:dir]] should read as [/S[:<dir>]], and

[/S[:<dir>]] means:
[          ] the /S switch is optional but if used,
 /S[:<dir>]  then the :<dir> part is optional but if used,
 /S:<dir>    then the : (U+003A,  Colon) is obligatory, and <dir> is a placeholder for which you must supply a value…

Described in Command-line syntax key:



Notation
Description




Text without brackets or braces
Items you must type as shown.


<Text inside angle brackets>
Placeholder for which you must supply a value.


[Text inside square brackets]
Optional items.


{Text inside braces}
Set of required items. You must choose one.


Vertical bar (|)
Separator for mutually exclusive items. You must choose one.


Ellipsis (…)
Items that can be repeated and used multiple times.




So just to supplement your answer with the information that would have made me understand the answer before asking.  \ refers to the root directory, such as in cd \.  And if I am already in the C:\ directory, then simply compact /u /i /s should have worked.  The reason I asked the question was because I was joining the s:\ thinking of that almost as a drive name, without realizing that the colon is simply a separator connected to the /s.
